# Why "net use * /delete" does not work but waits for confirmation in my PowerShell script?

Tags: .net, powershell, mapped-drive, net-use

I have a script where I want to disconnect from the mapped drives before I create a new PSDrive.

Otherwise I get this error:

> New-PSDrive : Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user
>   ,  using more than one user name, are not allowed.
>   Disconnect all previous connections  to the server or shared resource
>   and try again

So I have this line:

```
net use * /delete
```

(Unfortunately I could not find a way to disconnect from a specific mapped  drive just by providing the server name so far :( )

When PS comes to this line

> You have these remote connections:
>
> \\ServerName\SharedFolder Continuing will cancel the connections.

And then it stops executing.

**Is there a way to auto confirm disconnecting from the mapped drives automatically without confirmation (it does not have to be the net use /delete solution)?**

**Note that**: I run my script from the Powershell ISE PS promt

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Try this:

```
net use * /delete /y
```

The `/y` key makes it select Yes in prompt silently

Comment: And `/no` selected No in prompt silently.

Comment: Does the /Y param only work on the wild card delete?

Comment: This is so, so useful :) Saves typing in the names of shares

Answer (score 2):

With PowerShell 5.1 in Windows 10 you can use:

```
Get-SmbMapping | Remove-SmbMapping -Confirm:$false
```