# Run cmd.exe with C#,needs to input "Y"

Tags: c#

I want to run cmd command:"net use * /delete" with System.Diagnostics.Process,but the command needs to input "Y" or "N".

here is my code:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
string dosLine = "/C echo y | net use * /delete";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = dosLine;
proc.Start();
```

the codes do not work.
i also tried this:

```
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("net use * /delete");
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y");
```

still not work

what should i do?

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284106/why-net-use-delete-does-not-work-but-waits-for-confirmation-in-my-powershel

Answer (score -1):

`net use` takes a `/y` flag, so you can just pass that instead. You don't need to input it. You could also simplify your code like so:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "net";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "use * /delete /y";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.Start();
```